# Show that the equation of a line can be given as ℑm(αz+β)=0

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I've just started a non-Euclidean Geometry course and the book we are using has a very brief (and not-so-helpful) section on complex numbers that we sort of went over in class.  One of the questions is this: Given that α and β are complex constants and z = x + iy, show that ℑm(αz+β)=0  is the equation of a straight line.

The book doesn't even talk about this form "ℑm(αz+β)" until the questions, so I'm already a bit confused with the new symbols.  This is what I THINK the question is saying: If the imaginary part of a complex function (αz+β) is 0, then then function is a straight line on the Cartesian plane because if the iy of z is zero, that leaves us with just the real part, x. But what is beta then--a y-intercept? And how can I show this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imaginary part is not taken of $z$, but of $\alpha z+\beta$.

Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex, we can write them as $\alpha = \alpha_r + \mathrm i\alpha_i$ and $\beta = \beta_r + \mathrm i\beta_i$ where $\alpha_r,\alpha_i,\beta_r,\beta_i\in\mathbb R$.

Now $\alpha z + \beta = (\alpha_r + \mathrm i\alpha_i)(x + \mathrm i y) + (\beta_r +\mathrm i \beta_i)$. Expand the product, using the fact that $\mathrm i^2=-1$, and then you can easily take the imaginary part of that (it's everything that has an $\mathrm i$ as factor *after* expansion). Note that it contains *both* $x$ and $y$.

I assume you know what a general equation for a straight line in the $x$-$y$ plane looks like. Just compare the imaginary part you got from the above calculation with the general form.

As a bonus, you can also consider the real part. You'll find that this also describes a straight line, which is related to the line from the imaginary part (How?)

Comment: THANK YOU!  That makes a lot more sense and I can see how both parts are equations of a straight line.  I think the real part's straight line is perpendicular to the imaginary part's straight line, because the slope of the imaginary part's line would be -αi/αr and the slope of the real part's line would be αr/αi.  Is that how they're related?

Comment: @Jenjenjude: Yes, they are orthogonal to each other.